# Showing success message on a redirected page

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

There's two pages: one is index.php and another is add-name.php . add-name.php has a form which takes a name and after a successful submission, it redirects to index.php page where all the names is shown.
I was wondering how can I show a message that **the name has been added** on index.php page after add-name.php page redirects to index.php page when it's submitted.

**add-name.php**

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST"){
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    addName($name); // this addName function saves the name to a 
                       file called names.txt and index.php page 
                       uses this file to access all the names
    header("Location: index.php");

}

?>

<form action="add-name.php" method="POST">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
    <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Save">
</form>
```

Comment: hint: remember to call `exit()` after the `header()` line, otherwise the form will be displayed before the forwarding happens. To achieve your goal, you can either use cookie, or forward by a post request with a post field. Once the index.php detects the post field, a successful message will be displayed.

Comment: @Shakil - Use session. Init session and add some value in `add-name.php` and then check/destory session in `index.php`

Comment: One way of doing this might be to _overload_ `index.php` with a URL parameter, like so: `header('Location: index.php?message=Name+has+been+added');`. Then in `index.php` you would print out whatever you received in `$_GET['message']` (if anything).

Comment: @RoAchterberg, hey that's a good idea. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You're very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use session

`add-name.php`

```php
<?php

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] === "POST"){
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    // addName($name);
    session_start();
    $_SESSION["name"] = "added";
    header("Location: index.php");
    exit();
}

?>

<form action="add-name.php" method="POST">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
    <input type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Save">
</form>
```

`index.php`

```php
<?php
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION["name"]) && $_SESSION["name"] === "added") {
    echo "name added";
    unset($_SESSION["name"]);
} else {
    echo "just called";
}

# ...
```

Comment: your idea also works perfectly. Thanks for your nice organised piece of code.

Comment: @ShakilAhmed Please accept the answer if it is correct so that others can refer to this in the future.